# issue in using mock service as partner link in SOA BPEL11g

Tags: service, oracle11g, mocking, soa, bpel

I have created one Mock service in SOAPUI which I want to use as partner link in my bpel. I just have simply added one invoke activity which calls that partner link .But when I am trying to deploy the code I am getting the below error:
here was an error deploying/undeploying composite on soa_server1: Update Failed: ****Unable to find a WSDL that has a definition for service {http://xmlns.oracle.com/RLG_NEW/TestMockRest/BPELProcessMock}bpelprocessmock_client_ep and port BPELProcessMock_pt. Please make sure that the port attribute for the binding defined in the composite file is correct by checking the namespace service name and port name. In addition check that the WSDL associated with the binding namespace is imported and currently reachable (check the import nodes at the top of the composite file). Finally validate the HTTP proxy settings for the server..****

The mock service endpoint is opening properly in my browser and able to hit the same from SOAPUI as well.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Sreeparna

Answer (score 0):

When you try to invoke the partner link, under the Partner role webservice interface, if you can access to all the methods available in Operations then your partner link is in sink with BPEL,

So try to access the operations and if it responds then your build should be success.